# If two objects collide, will the collision force be twice as big as the original force?

Tags: collision

Say, if we have two trucks travelling towards eachother at 60m/s, and those two trucks carry the same payload, and are the same model (aka they're exactly the same), will the collision force be as if just one truck crashed into a wall at 120m/s?

Theoretically the forces will balance each other out, but it won't always be this way.

Comment: Are you familiar with the similar problem of a horse pulling a rope attached to a pole compared to two horses pulling a single rope in opposite directions?

Comment: Do you want elastic collisions or 'smashing' collisions?

Comment: Set up an experiment and test it ;)

Comment: To paraphrase the duplicate answer, the answer is that a truck at 120mph hitting a wall is more forceful than two trucks each at 60mph colliding head-on.